# $a\mid b+c \implies a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$ ,which is the case when this statement is true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I think that I've read this statement somewhere, but I am not sure if it's true or not.
If you have any idea, please post it here, and thank you.

I know there is a lot of counterexamples to this statement but I'm asking for a way (not an example) that lets this true for every $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$

Comment: Hint: if you let $\,c = -b\,$ then it implies $\,a\mid b\,$ for all $\,a,b\,$ for which there are obvious counterexamples. Please try special cases before posing such questions, i.e. spend some nontrivial effort first.

Comment: The statement is false and counterexamples are easy to find. Maybe you read something like if $a|(b+c)$ and $a|b$ then $a|c$. Or if $a$ is prime then $a|bc \implies a|b$ or $a|c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its true if both $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$. It is not true if, only one of the two ($b$ or $c$) is multiple of $a$.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is **not true** in general.

**Counterexample**: $6$ divides ($3+3$) but $6$ does not divide $3$.

An example for when it **is true**: $6$ divides $(6+6)$ and, of couse, $6$ divides $6$.

Comment: I know this but is there any exception to this

Comment: @Yassir It can be true: $6$ divides $6+6$ and, of couse, $6$ divides $6$.

Answer (score 0):

$2\mid 3+5$, but $2$ does neither divide $3$ nor $5$.